# Supporting different compile SDK version for my library

Tags: android

I have a android library for push notifications and with the release of android Oreo and notification channels I moved up my compile SDK version to 26 and started using support library 26.1.0 along with it to support channel features.
Some of my users are still on compile SDK version 25 and are reluctant to move up the compile version to 26. Also as a best practise most of them want have the support library and compile SDK version on same major version.
This is causing and issue for me on how to support multiple compile version. I don't want to maintain different SDKs for different compile sdk version.

Current implementation: I have added support-compat 26 in provided scope and expect the app developer to add it as compile/implemention.

Old versions can be used but concern here is how to manage bug fixes, enhancements and features

Comment: "Some of my users are still on compile SDK version 25 and are reluctant to move up the compile version to 26" -- that is not a good plan on their part. However, they should be able to still use an older version of your library, one that also uses `compileSdkVersion 25`, right?

Comment: yes they can, but I can't keep adding bug fixes and features to the old ones. To use them they need to update, main problem is rolling out features, enhancements and bug fixes

Comment: Correct. That is not significantly different than with any other dependencies of theirs, such as the support library. If they want to stay current, they need to be in position to stay current on everything. Right now, those users are implicitly stating that they *don't* want bug fixes, as otherwise they would be on the current support library version rather than a v25 edition. If they want you to have up-to-date bug fixes/features for multiple API levels, charge them enough money to make that worth your while.